# Change Facebook Account / log out completely using Firebase and Android

Tags: android, facebook, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

i´m not able to find any solution that solves my Problem.

I use Firebase and Facebook to sign up to my app.

When I first sign up to my app, i get the following screen:

[Facebook First Login-Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDG1p.jpg)

I sign out from Firebase and Facebook using the following Lines of Code:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
```

When I´m trying after that to sign in with Facebook again, I get the following Screen:

[Facebook Second Login-Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1hyO.jpg)

I´m only able to continue with the Account I used before.
I want to come back to the first Screen, where I have to enter E-Mail an Password so I could Sign in with another Facebook Account if I want.

On Stackoverflow I found the following promising Code:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                AccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(null);
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }
        }).executeAsync();
    }
```

But this solved also not my Problem.

After that I get the following Screen:

[Facebook alternate Second Login-Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZfI9.jpg)

I would by very thankful for any help and sorry for any English mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code before you click on facebook login button

```
    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
            accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
            DebugLog.infoLog("Token Changed Called");
            if (currentAccessToken == null) {
              LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(mActivity, Arrays.asList(permissionList));;
            }
        }
    };
    AccessToken.refreshCurrentAccessTokenAsync();
```

After above code just call login code as mentioned below (use handler to call below code with 1 milliseconds wait time):

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(mActivity, Arrays.asList(permissionList));
```

Comment: Can anyone write it in kotlin?