# Android Firebase Auth Facebook how to sign out to change facebook account in Kotlin?

Tags: android, firebase, facebook, kotlin, firebase-authentication

The facebook developer documentation is not complete and then I'm asking here how to log out of facebook and then when we click on Login with facebook we get the activity which ask us with what account we want to login? By default when we press on the login facebook button it logs in automatically without ask user with what account he wants to log in.

I have already implemented the facebook log out :

```
val auth = Firebase.auth
 val providerData = auth.currentUser!!.providerData

    if (providerData[providerData.size - 1].providerId == "facebook.com") {
                        auth.signOut()
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
    }
```

I saw a similar post [Change Facebook Account / log out completely using Firebase and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248015/change-facebook-account-log-out-completely-using-firebase-and-android) but it is in java and I wonder if there is a better way to do it?

Comment: In addition to that, have you tried FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut(); ?

Comment: yeah the auth is equal to Firebase.auth. It's the same as FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

Answer (score 1):

```
binding.btnSignOut.setOnClickListener {
        val user = Firebase.auth.currentUser
        user?.let {
            for (profile in it.providerData) {
                if (profile.providerId == "google.com") {
                    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN
                    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
                    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut().addOnCompleteListener {
                        Firebase.auth.signOut()
                        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.Signedout, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        startActivity(intent)
                        this.finish()
                    }
                }
                if (profile.providerId == "facebook.com") {
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()
                    Firebase.auth.signOut()
                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    Toast.makeText(this, R.string.Signedout, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    startActivity(intent)
                    this.finish()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```